# how to protect master page controller affected in child page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller and model in my asp masterpage
so,that my other content pages not working.Content pages having seperate controller and model in angular js

Comment: You should provide more info. Explain with the code and describe the issue you are facing/what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `controller as` syntax? You may find it here [ngController doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController).

So you may isolate your master page controller by naming it somehow, for example MainMasterPageCtrl.